# How to use python logging rather than print

Tags: python

I dont get logging in python.

I run the below and i see nothing.  Why?

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info('Start reading database')
logger.info('Updating records ...')
logger.debug('Hi, foo')
```

Of course a simple print works

Comment: How are you running it? Seems to work for me.

Comment: Can confirm with python 3.4, works for me too. Output is  `INFO:__main__:Start reading database  
INFO:__main__:Updating records ...  
`

Comment: Note that the output is to stderr. Is your stderr redirected or something like that?

Comment: Try `logging.basicConfig(filename="/path/to/output.log",filemode="w",level=logging.INFO)`

Comment: Here is one [link](http://victorlin.me/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python)...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set your default level to INFO, DEBUG-level messages will not get printed.

---

There are two components to setting up logging.  Configuring the *default logging level*; and then configuring where the logs will be written to. Everything else is optional.

There are a few [examples in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html) for various scenarios.

The simplest example to get started with logging is:

```
import logging

logging.warning('Hello World')
```

This works with the built-in defaults, which output to the console for the warning logging level. The logging level you set is important, because if you try the following:

```
import logging

logging.info('This is a simple message')
```

You will see that nothing gets printed. This is because only those levels *above* the default level get printed; and since the default level is WARNING, any messages at the INFO level do not get printed.

The ordering is (from lowest to highest level):

1. DEBUG
2. INFO
3. WARNING
4. ERROR
5. CRITICAL